# The type or namespace name 'ThreadContext' does not exist in the namespace 'log4net'

Tags: log4net, sitecore

I am trying to use the following line of code to pass a property to a log4net appender:

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["LogName"] = processID.ToString();
```

but, when I compile I keep getting the error *The type or namespace name 'ThreadContext' does not exist in the namespace 'log4net'*

I am "using" log4net and I am including the Sitecore.Logging DLL in the references of the project. Log4net is being used by this project and both loggers and appenders work just fine. The only thing is that when I type log4net in code and type the ".", intellisense doesn't diaply any reference to either *GlobalContent* or *ThreadContent*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Sitecore uses an older version of log4net in their Sitecore.Logging because there is no ThreadContext class present there, or they removed it from their implementation.
They use version 1.2.0 as far as i can see.

Comment: I see. So the solution is to download a more recent DLL and include it or is it going to be an issue? Let me try and see what happens :)

Comment: Which Sitecore version do you use? In my 6.5, there is no separate log4net DLL anymore (it's compiled as Sitecore.Logging.dll) and version 6.6 also uses the log4net 1.2.0, so that won't help. -- I guess you could try to take the latest log4net source code and compile it as Sitecore.Logging.dll but it would leave you with a custom sitecore build... Maybe there is an entire different approach to your problem (don't know why you need to access the appender properties)

Comment: We are using Sitecore 6.5.0. We are building a web service logger that logs the RAW XML for every request/response. All the coding is done. The only thing we need to do is to have each pair request/response in its own file, named something like {guid}.log

Comment: Maybe you should add a new appender in the web.config and then implement your own logger. You can see in web.config how that is done for WebDAV. Use Reflector or dotPeek to look under the hood of Sitecore.Diagnostics.WebDAV to see how they did it there.

Comment: But the WebDAV one has the following setting: <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/WebDAV.log.{date}.txt" /> --- I was thinking more along the lines of <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="$(dataFolder)/logs/SitecoreServices/ItemService/log.%property{LogName}.txt" />

Comment: Once you implement your own logger and associated appender, you are free to configure any logfile pattern in there.